# Apache shutdown unexpexctedly. Error is still there despite changing the ports

Tags: apache, xampp, port

I have even changed the ports Apache httpd conf and httpd-ssl conf but errors are still there. Please let me know if there any services to be stopped. I am using php 7.3 and xampp control panel v3.2.4

Status change detected: running

```
3:34:17 PM  [Apache]    Status change detected: stopped
3:34:17 PM  [Apache]    Error: Apache shutdown unexpectedly.
3:34:17 PM  [Apache]    This may be due to a blocked port, missing dependencies, 
3:34:17 PM  [Apache]    improper privileges, a crash, or a shutdown by another method.
3:34:17 PM  [Apache]    Press the Logs button to view error logs and check
3:34:17 PM  [Apache]    the Windows Event Viewer for more clues
3:34:17 PM  [Apache]    If you need more help, copy and post this
```

Comment: Some apps can use port 80. Aren't you using e.g. Skype?
You can check it https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48198/how-can-you-find-out-which-process-is-listening-on-a-port-on-windows

Comment: I have uninstalled skype but issue is still there despite changing port 80.

Comment: Check the error log - in XAMP it's the button Logs

Comment: Its showing : Server certificate does NOT include an ID which matches the server name ?